# Problems with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm getting this error Please help: I'm getting error with private class thehandler which is "The type second thehandler must implement the abstract
method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

Note: imports are imported. I want a solution but not abstract because It crashes whole program for some reasons.

```
public class Second extends JFrame {

    private JTextField item1;
    private JTextField item2;
    private JTextField item3;
    private JPasswordField itemp;
    public Second(){
        super("Game");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        item1 = new JTextField(10);
        add(item1);
        item2 = new JTextField("Enter Text Here");
        add(item2);
        item3 = new JTextField("uneditable",20);
        item3.setEditable(false);
        add(item3);
        itemp = new JPasswordField("PASSWORD");
        add(itemp); 
        thehandler handler = new thehandler();
        item1.addActionListener(handler);
        item2.addActionListener(handler);
        item3.addActionListener(handler);
        itemp.addActionListener(handler);

    }
    private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
        public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            String string = "";

            if(event.getSource()==item1)
                string = String.format("It's: %s", event.getActionCommand());
            else if(event.getSource()==item2)
                string = String.format("It's: %s", event.getActionCommand());
            else if(event.getSource()==item3)
                string = String.format("It's: %s", event.getActionCommand());
            else if(event.getSource()==itemp)
                string = String.format("It's: %s", event.getActionCommand());

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);






        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Java is case sensitive

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that A even :)